# Setting up project is eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, svn, maven, setup-project

I want to setup my work project in Eclipse, with following features:
1) Connect to SVN repository
2) It is a maven - multi module project
3) It is a spring project

If I import this project as Maven project I am not able to connect it to SVN repository.
If I check - out SVN repository, I am not able to set it up as Maven/Spring project.

And ideally I want to make it hot deployable, (as eclipse dynamic web project), so Development can be efficient.

How can I possibly do this.

I have setup eclipse Juno SR1 with Maven, STS, and SVN plugins.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you explain what messages you are getting when you are not able to connect to the SVN repository or when you try to set it up as a Maven/Spring project.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is follow the below steps :-

1. Checkout from svn to your local drive.
2. As it is a mave nbuild project you will have the `pom.xml` file in the root of the project. Do a `mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0` on the project.

3.Open eclipse and go to `File-->Import--> Existing projects into workspace`.

This should do.

FYR see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-do-use-maven-to-create-a-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 0):

After the project is checked out into the Eclipse workspace, just remove the project by using the following action: -

```
right click at the project ---> delete ---> click ok
```

Please take a note, **do not check** the check box named "*Delete project content on disk*". We have just want to remove and re-import again.

All we need to do is re-importing by using the following action: -

```
File ---> Import ---> Maven ---> Existing Maven projects
```

This will help us to integrate the Maven with the SVN in Eclipse. We will see the revision information after the project name, folders, packages, classes, etc.

Anyhow to use Maven in the Eclipse, you should install the [Maven Integration (m2e)](http://eclipse.org/m2e/). Furthermore there is a useful plug-in to integrate the Eclipse WTP with the Maven as well. It is named [Maven Integration for WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/).

I hope this may help.